# I am trying to create a page or pages in laravel that shows a spefic client dashboard

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For example : If I select from a list of clients ( company names ) and it takes you to a dashboard or a page that displays only that company data. Then when you data while on that page on some content on the dashboard you are still within that company until you change it to a new company.

Forgive me if it not very clear as I dont know the proper terminology.
Can you tell me what I am describing or term that would allow me to search for how to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?.

Comment: Well Its not that I tried anything but I i am looking for the terms on where to begin. I am just trying to describe what i am wanting to do.

Comment: Is there a topic or term that relates to those type of functions?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing